# Can an Incandescent Bulb be considered as a heater?

Tags: energy

Due to an experiment, I need a small heater (around 70 to 100 watts). I intend to use an incandescent bulb so it can act as a heater. What I wonder here is will a 70 watts Incandescent Bulb be equal to a 70 watts heater?

Comment: you can definitely use it i use it to warm my hand in winter day's got severe burn's also

Comment: Yes, see http://heatball.de/en/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb#Efficiency_and_environmental_impact):

> **Approximately 90%** of the power consumed by an incandescent light bulb
>   is emitted as heat, rather than as visible light.

So, yes, the incandescent bulb can be used as a heater and, in fact, has been used as a heater.  For example, see:  [Easy-Bake oven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easy-Bake_Oven).

> The original toy used an ordinary incandescent light bulb as a heat
>   source

Comment: would an electric Heater at 70 watts emit more than 90% of the power consumed as heat?

Comment: @Malachi,  *"Electric resistance heating converts nearly 100% of the energy in the electricity to heat."*   http://energy.gov/energysaver/articles/electric-resistance-heating

Comment: so then he would need a little more than a 70 watt lightbulb to be considered a 70 watt heater, right?

Comment: @Malachi, that's correct.

Comment: If 90% is converted to heat then a 70 Watt bulb would produce ( 100/90 * 70 ) 63 Watts of heat.  A 77.78 Watt bulb would produce 70 Watts of heat. Since they usually sell 60, 75 and 100 Watt bulbs the best bulb is probably a 75 Watt version.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever bulb is used, basically all the power consumed will go into heating the environment, with the notable exception being any photons that escape through a window or some such thing.

Different styles of bulb have different visible light-heat ratios, but even the visible light emitted will simply bounce around the room a few times and deposit all its useful energy into random thermal motions. You know these photons cease existing, at least in the visible range, because when you turn off a light, the room essentially instantly goes dark.

Incandescent bulbs work better at heating than, e.g., certain fluorescent bulbs for a given amount of visible lighting because they consume more power (and thus emit more direct heat) per unit desired light. However, even if you designed a light bulb that emitted 100% of its photons in the visible range, that power (small though it would be) would all go into heating its environment.